# does npm install command for node package manager runs npm build automatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, node-modules

I have integrated a reusable node js project to azure  and published the node project to azure artifact store for npm using command 'npm publish'.

And i have a azure task in pipeline which uses this reusable package in my main project with yaml content like below:

```
npm install <my reusable package name from internal azure npm registry>
npm install //this installs all other packages based on main project's package.json
```

Does npm command 'npm install ' runs 'npm build' command right after downloading package  ? if it does then i do not want to buid my npm package before publishing.

I want to make sure when someone install my reusable package the dist folder is available.

e.g. When i install npm package 'vue-tabulator' after installation i noticed it populated dist folder. I am not sure if this happens for all the packages.

Comment: no it doesn't. U have to npm run build mannually

Comment: So the dist folder for each package installed will be created only after running npm run build when each pacakge has 'build':'npm run build' script in their package,json. Am i right?